# System.InvalidOperationException at Dapper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, orm, dapper

i'm going to use dapper as my ORM in asp .net project.
So the problem is, i'm going to execute my procedure to return get data by Id.
If the Id is not exist, the error appeard like this

[Sequence contains no elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er00K.png)

is there any solution to prevent the error by using dapper? because the other solution using entity framework.

here's my code

```
var SP_Name = "SP_GetSupplierById";
parameters.Add("@Id", Id);
var getSupplierById = connection.QuerySingle<Supplier>(SP_Name,parameters,commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure);
return getSupplierById;
```

and here's my procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GetSupplierById
@Id int
AS
    SELECT * from TB_M_Supplier where id = @Id;
RETURN 0
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`QuerySingle` asserts that there is exactly one row returned; not zero, not multiple. If zero is acceptable, then you can use `QuerySingleOrDefault` - and check for the default, which will be `null` in the case of reference types (classes). `QuerySingleOrDefault` only asserts that there aren't multiple rows; zero is fine.

So

```cs
var getSupplierById = connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<Supplier>(SP_Name,parameters,commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure);
return getSupplierById; // todo: consider null
```